# How to build touch gestures with swipe-detect?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

I want to create touch gestures, like in Chromium for my Electron app. It should just do two simple things: Load the next page, when I swipe left and the previous page, when I swipe right.

I found this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/swipe-detect, which seems to be able to do it. It takes a TARGET_DOMAIN_NODE, which I guess is the screen, a CALLBACK, which I guess is the function to call on a swipe and the threshold for swipe length.

I wanted to use

```
import swipeDetect from 'swipe-detect';
```

in the main.js, but I am getting an unexpected identifier error. So I guess I have to write

```
const swipeDetect = require ('swipe-detect');
```

as for other packages.

swipeDetect outputs left, right, up or down, so I wrote this simple function and put it at the top of the main.js

```
function swipeHandler (direction) {
  if(direction == 'left') {
    parent.document.getElementById(1).contentWindow.history.forward();
  }

  if(direction == 'right') {
    parent.document.getElementById(1).contentWindow.history.back();
  }
}
```

Then for swipeDetect I put

```
swipeDetect(electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay(), swipeHandler(), 150);
```

But I am getting

```
export default function(target, callback, threshold=150) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:752:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:601:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\folder\main.js:17:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:808:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
```

I guess the format is wrong. Already tried to put electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay() in {}, but that doesn't change anything.